# Ionic 3 Angular 5 How fetch data and transform it to Observable in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hello I need to fetch data coming from API and then based on response return Observable in ngOnInit.

@Edit Basically `this.dayOverViewByGroup` should be fully downloaded from api when is returned in `fetchChildrensData()` => `return Observable.of(this.dayOverViewByGroup)`.

@Edit2 Added code for `getDayOverViewByGroupId`

ngOnInit

```js
ngOnInit() {
    const filter$: Observable<string> = this.filterControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(100), 
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      share()
    );
    this.dayOverViewByGroup$ = this.fetchChildrensData().pipe(
      map(days => days.map(day => (
        {
          ...day,
          filteredChildren$: filter$.pipe(this.filterFrom(day.children))
        }
      )))
    );
  }
```

fetchChildrensData function

```js
 fetchChildrensData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return Observable.of(this.dayOverViewByGroup)
 }
```

Functions that handle API call

```js
getChildrens(date, groupId) {
    return this.attendanceService.getDayOverViewByGroupId(date, groupId).then(
      (res1: any) => {
        let dayOverViewByGroup = res1.mobile_employee_dayoverview;
        this.dayOverViewByGroup = dayOverViewByGroup;
        this.appFunctionCtrl.dismissLoader();  
      },
      (error) => console.log('Error occured in this.attendanceService.getDayOverViewByGroupId()', error)
    );

  }
```

```js
getDayOverViewByGroupId(currentDate = null, groupId) {
    let that = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      that.wsseGenerator.getWSSEHeader().then(header => {
        header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
        let paramsData = {
          groupId: groupId,
          currentDate: currentDate
        };
        let params = that.serializeObject(paramsData);
        that.http.post(`${that.baseUrl}/dayoverview?${params}`, null, options).timeout(this.timeTimeout).subscribe((success: any) => {
          resolve(success);
        }, (err) => {

          this.appFunctionCtrl.dismissLoader();
          if (err.name == 'TimeoutError') {
            this.alert.present();
          }
          else {
            reject(err);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: It would be best to work with Observables from the beginning (i.e. in your Service) and change `this.attendanceService.getDayOverViewByGroupId` to return an Observable instead of a Promise. Could you post the code of `this.attendanceService.getDayOverViewByGroupId`.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the post with `this.attendanceService.getDayOverViewByGroupId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return an Observable from your Service that doesn't throw any errors so you can directly use the AsyncPipe in you Component to subscribe (Also see: [Why handle errors with catchError and not in the subscribe error callback in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790621/9423231)).

Convert Api calls that you can't change and return Promises to Observables with `from` and use RxJS operators from then on (I'm presuming `this.wsseGenerator.getWSSEHeader()` is such a call).

Use `switchMap` to map to a different Observable, `pluck` or `map` to extract / transform returned data, `catchError` to do things on errors and return an Observable that doesn't throw any errors, `finalize` to do things when your Observable errors or completes.

In your Service:

```ts
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { switchMap, map, timeout, catchError, finalize } from "rxjs/operators";

getDayOverViewByGroupId(currentDate = null, groupId): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.from(this.wsseGenerator.getWSSEHeader()).pipe( // use from to convert Promise to Observable
    switchMap(header => {
      header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
      let paramsData = {
        groupId: groupId,
        currentDate: currentDate
      };
      let params = that.serializeObject(paramsData);
      // map to your http request
      return this.http.post(`${that.baseUrl}/dayoverview?${params}`, null, options);
    }),
    map(this.getRelevantData), // get relevant data from http response
    timeout(this.timeTimeout),
    catchError(error => { // handle errors and return an Observable that doesn't error
      console.log('Error occured in this.attendanceService.getDayOverViewByGroupId()', error);
      if (error.name == 'TimeoutError') {
          this.alert.present();
      }
      // you have to think about what default value you want to return on errors, null can be ok
      return Observable.of(null); 
    }),
    finalize(() => this.appFunctionCtrl.dismissLoader()) // do stuff on error and complete
  );
}

private getRelevantData(response): any { // <-- don't return 'any' in your real code, create interfaces to type your data if you can
  let dayOverViewByGroup = response.mobile_employee_dayoverview;
  dayOverViewByGroup.forEach(element => {
    // do your thing
  }
  console.log('dayOverViewByGroup', dayOverViewByGroup)
  return dayOverViewByGroup;
}
```

In your Component:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.dayOverViewByGroup$ = this.attendanceService.getDayOverViewByGroupId( .. ).pipe( 
    // If the Observable from your service can emit 'null' and you do
    // map(days => days.map(..)) you will get an error 
    // so you might have to handle this case here

    // 1. Option: filter out 'null' and 'undefined' values before your 'map' and don't emit anything
    filter(Boolean)

    // 2. Option: handle 'null' and 'undefined' in your map function
    map(days => {     
      if (days) {
        days.map( .. )
      } else {
        // do something else or don't do anything at all, i.e. remove the else case
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have some problems with "Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?" in service and pipe is not a function. I think its a import problems.

Comment: Did you `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`? If you get pipe is not a function you're not using an Observable where there should be one.

Comment: Thank you I was importing from wrong package. Now I have, `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9_rxjs__.Observable.from is not a function` You mentioned about `this.wsseGenerator.getWSSEHeader()` how to check if this is not a problem in that case?

Comment: Try `import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';` and use `from` without `Observable` like `from(this.wsseGenerator.getWSSEHeader())`. `this.wsseGenerator.getWSSEHeader()` returns a Promise right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes `this.wsseGenerator.getWSSEHeader()` returns public getWSSEHeader(): Promise<HttpHeaders>

Comment: Removed Observable from `from`. Error is gone, I have array from api in `getRelevantData` - however there is notthing rendered on a page. My ngOnInit

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Verthon/4673db59f4c2b23409bf94302e6d3638

Comment: You should be able to fix problems like this yourself. Add `console.log` to every relevant code branch to see how the code flow is where your data gets stuck. Hint: when does `(days && days === undefined)` evaluate to `true`?

Comment: Thank you, I greatly appreciate your help.